# How to check if all value in loop true value or any of it has false value

Tags: php, foreach

How do i check if all product in cart allow cash on delivery while looping through the data.

Example i have items in cart

car

```
itemname |  cod |
---------|------|-------------- 
  car    |  1   |
 phone   |  0   |
  gun    |  1   |
```

PHP CODE

```
foreach($mycart as $row){
    if($row->cod){
        $allItemAllowCod = true;
    }else{
        $allItemAllowCod = false;
     }
}
```

What am trying to do is once any record has `cod` with 0 value that `$allItemAllowCod` should return false to but if all item cod value is 1 it will return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a break statement this will stop the foreach execution

```
foreach($mycart as $row){
    if($row->cod){
        $allItemAllowCod = true;
    }else{
        $allItemAllowCod = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: I would suggest defining `$allItemAllowCod = true;` before the loop and then only have one if-statement without any `else` in the loop: `if (0 == $row->cod) { $allItemAllowCod = false; break; }`

Comment: Yup, that's much cleaner!

Comment: Nice it worked, but please is possible to determine if all `cod` has 0 or some has 1 and some has 0?

Comment: @PhilipJems - Yes, it's possible but that's another question. This answer solves the current question. Please don't move the goal post for your question after you've gotten a correct answer. Post a new question instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if i post another question it will be down voted should i just update my question?

Comment: @PhilipJems - Why would it be down voted? Just accept this answer if it solved the this question and post a new question (with this updated code) and ask the new question. Changing this question will make this answer (which is a correct answer) incorrect. Nobody will want to keep wasting time answering you if you keep changing the question.

Comment: If you do it the way Magnus told, you wouldn't need a break statement, because the $allItemAllowCod will not turn to true in the foreach loop but only before. So you can have a second variable which will turn false only if there is a 1 in cod. If this variable is true then it means you haven't got any 1s.